# Issue submitting iOS app from xcode which claims SDK 12.0 is less than SDK 11

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've been trying to send an app from xcode today and keep getting the same error message:

[image]

This app is a iMessage sticker pack if that makes a difference.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Edit: I was able to send an update for another app, **this seems to be iMessage Sticker pack specific**.

Comment: Which version of Xcode did you use? - You need 10.1 or later (You should be using 10.2.1) as you must use 12.1, not 12.0 as per the message (It is after March 2019).

Comment: as mentioned below I've updated to 10.1, and can't update further because OSX can't be updated to Mojave. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

While the message talks about the iOS 11 SDK, it also states that you must use the **12.1 SDK** after March 2019.

Your app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK, so you will need to update Xcode to at least version 10.1, however 10.2.1 is the latest.

Comment: I've updated Xcode to 10.1 but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Make sure you have performed a "clean build folder" and then re-archive your app.  You may also need to delete your derived data folder.

Comment: Also, if you are going to continue iOS development you will need to start planning for a Mac upgrade; probably early next year Apple will require you to build against the iOS 13 SDK, which means you will need Xcode 11 and a Mac running at least Mojave, preferably Catalina.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the upcoming (totally not planned) obsolescence. We're in the process of begrudgingly sourcing another mac. Thanks for the advice.
Will give clearing the cache try

Comment: I tried cleaning the build and removing the derived data folder but still getting that same error

Comment: To be fair, I have a 5 year old MacBook Pro that is running Catalina; If your Mac can't run Mojave, it is over 7 years old!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194919/discussion-between-paulw11-and-peopletookallthegoodnames).

Comment: You could try completely removing Xcode and re-installing 10.1

Comment: We've tried that, and I also created a new project but it's still giving us this error